# Can i use cordova to develop android app that uses opencv.js?

Tags: cordova, opencv

I want to use cordova to make android application since javascript is the language that I'm familiar with. But the problem is my project needs to use opencv.js. and other libraries. is cordova still the best option to make an android app for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are compatible with some devop's work because OpenCV is a library, so you can use cordova in front and Php + OpenCv in backend.

https://github.com/php-opencv/php-opencv-examples

Honestly native developpement ll be better render, but cordova ll be faster de deploy.
So you need to measure what you need exactly before choosing cordova.

Comment: So I can use any javascript library and developed it using cordova as mobile app?